# extjs label change font color using cls

Tags: extjs6

in my extjs I have a xtype label and am just trying to use cls to change font color but its not working.  can you see what I am doing wrong?

```
                            layout: 'column',
                        items: [
                            {
                                columnWidth: 0.5,
                                xtype: 'label',
                                cls: 'myLabelCRM',
                                text: 'Account Data1'
                            },
```

--scss

```
.myLabelCRM .x-component-default {
color: red;
}
```

Comment: so I found this and it worked... .myLabelCRM,
.myLabelCRM .x-form-item-label,
.myLabelCRM .x-form-display-field{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;.           can someone tell me how I was supposed to know this... like where to find in documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try using userCls or componentCls instead of cls. These might be more direct to the component. It is not included in their documentation that you also need to add the generated component classes to your SCSS, but if you want to know what classes to add just inspect the element and get the classes from there.